# Duplicate records in one row

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
ID DEGREE  DEGREE1  DEGREE2
1  BS
1          MS
1                    PHD
2 BA
2         MA
```

I'm expecting to get the following results

```
ID DEGREE  DEGREE1  DEGREE2
1  BS      MS       PHD
2  BA      MA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple aggregration and max should do it..

```
SELECT ID, max(Degree) degree, max(Degree1) degree1, max(Degree2) Degree2
FROM table
GROUP BY Id
```

(must be a C/java programmer 0 based degree  even though they have 3.)

This does assume there will only be 1 degree per row / id.